# Impact of adding a ; after the statement of a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

What is the difference between a for loop with and without a semicolon after the initial statement? For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x ; i++) {...

   //versus

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++); {...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: English please!

Comment: Tienes que escribir tu pregunta en inglés, porque aquí solo usamos inglés

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/ es para preguntas en español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop with a semicolon at the end doesn't execute any instruction inside the loop, and the other one executes whats inside the curly braces.

Comment: More precisely: a `for` loop takes a statement.  A statement could be a single statement like `x = 3`, a block statement like `{ s1; s2; }`, or an empty statement.  When you see a `;` at the end of a for-loop, this is an empty statement.  It's not good style to do this, as it confuses people; better to use empty braces `{ }` as this is more obvious what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces, which look like {}, are usually used for loops and if statements. The curly braces hold lines of code. The semicolons are used at the end of lines of code and tell the computer that its reached the end of a statement.

It can get a little tricky when setting up loops, among other things. Below are some examples.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    //do something
}
```

As you can see, the i++ doesn't use a semicolon at the end. Notice that this curly brace doesn't need a semicolon.

The curly braces can also be used for things like holding Strings in an array like so:

```
String[] stringArray = {"dog", "cat", "bird"};
```

As you can again see, the end of this statment requires a semicolon.

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses OP's concern: `for (...);` with a semicolon is valid syntax, but has a different meaning.